# Is there a way to install rethinking packages on colab (python)

Tags: python, statistics, package, google-colaboratory

Installing rethinking statistical packages on colab such as quap and so on?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?  what is a rethinking package ?

Comment: Rethinking is a statistical package that I need to install all these import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
from quap import quap
import arviz as az
import statsmodels.api as sm
import math

But the quap, arviz and watermark is not installing/loading on collab.

Thanks